# Winforms: Background worker - best way to KILL it

Tags: winforms

I noticed the background worker has a backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync(); method, but when you call this method, you still need to add code in the worker method, to check for a cancellation request. All this is polite and fine, but what if you just want to KILL the thread immediately? How is this done.

I want to annihilate the thread, do not pass begin and do not collect 200.

Comment: If you really really want to be able to shut down the process from outside lovelessly, is there a reason you're not going for Thread and its Abort()-method?

Comment: Yes, I have code calling a web service method, waiting for this operation to complete takes forever, and the user will think something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like a good idea...

A better programmer practice should be to check CancellationPending regularly on the thread.

```
if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)   
{   
     e.Cancel = true;    
     return;   
}
```

EDIT:

Anyway the backgroundworker doesn't support it (as it's a bad programming practice), But if you really want to do that: just create yourself a normal Thread using the `Thread` Class